# Empty subfolders in home directory

Tags: chown

Today when I started my system , All subfolders  of my "home folder" were locked. So after reading different posts  i ran chown command. As a result all locks were removed but these subfolders are now empty . Where my data/files inside these folders went? However the files present in home directory are okay.only the files in subfolders are missing.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are the subfolders on mounted devices?

Comment: I have only one hard disk ( only sda1)  and no other device attached. Now how can I found the sub folders are on the mounted device?